# What did I do wrong in my Database Query with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database and a table in it which is looking like this

ID Picture Description.

In my PHP-Code I try to get the "Picture" which is just a text right now and the Description. But I always get

> Undefined Index: Description
>   Undefined Index: Picture

Here my Code:

```
   <?php include ("db.php"); 

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

 if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "SELECT Picture, Description FROM family WHERE ID = 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql)
or die ("MySQL-Error: " . $conn->error); 

 if ($result->num_rows >0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 


echo "Pic: " . $row["Picture"]. " - Description: " . $row["Description"]. " 

}
}

 else {
echo "Not good";
}
$conn->close();
echo "Connected successfully"; ?>
```

What does the error mean

EDIT: I solved it changed `mysqli_fetch_row` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: `print_r($row)` or follow the manual.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_row` returns an enumerated array starting at 0, not an associative array. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
```

you should use `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`